Finite nets, numerical invariants
I am studying the following paper: Finite Nets, Numerical Invariants (R. H. Bruck) for a school project about finite geometry.
While I understand most of what is written, some points are rapidly mentioned and I can't find a proper justification.
Namely:

"Moreover, $\Phi(N)$ is the (positive) greatest common divisor of the integers represented on $N$" (page 95)
"then  $\Phi(N)$ is the least common multiple  $\Phi(N) = [h_1, ..., h_r]$ (page 97)"

If somebody there has already studied this paper (or knows another which is more detailed) and can help me I would really appreciate it.
